# Why won't this code work? (Im a complete noob in js, may have done some obvious mistakes)

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do here is to apply an eventListener to every element of one class, and then, after user clicked on one of those elements, he will be prompted dependent on the index of that element in the class array.

Also, yes, I know that it can be done in many different ways, but I want it to work in this particular one (if it is possible).

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("openbtn");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        switchBtn(i);
    });
}


function switchBtn(index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        prompt("case0");
        break;
             
    case 1:
        prompt("case1");
        break;
             
    default:
        alert(index);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: By not working do you mean nothing happens when you click on buttons?

Comment: Yes, nothing happened when I clicked on buttons, so I changed the let to var of confusion. The real problem was that the soft I was using to run my code did not support ES6, which is why the code was not working (took a while to figure out that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the event handler functions share the same `i` variable, which is equal to `buttons.length` at the end of the loop, so the default case will be used each time. Instead, use `let` for lexical scoping.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("openbtn");
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        switchBtn(i);
    });
}


function switchBtn(index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        prompt("case0");
        break;

    case 1:
        prompt("case1");
        break;

    default:
        alert(index);
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="openbtn">case 0</button>
<button class="openbtn">case 1</button>
<button class="openbtn">default</button>
```